# Не работает firebase после скачивания с play market

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Мобильное приложение после скачивания с `play market` не показывает содержание с `firebase`, но когда идет установки на эмулятор, то все работает, все данные с `firebase`  отображаются
Приложение подписано release ключом с google console (ключ загрузки)
Настроена `firebase` на хеш ключа загрузки и подключена к `google console`

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вы неосторожно согласились на подписывание приложения в маркете ключом гугла. И у вас теперь 3 ключа: дебажный, релизный и маркетовский. Наверное, в консоли Firebase у вас указаны SHA-1 отпечатки только 2 ключей - дебажного и релизного. Верно ли это?

Comment: да, есть 3 ключа, дебажний, релиз, маркет. Сейчас в firebase два ключа релиз (Сертификат загрузки с маркет) и маркет (Сертификат подписи приложения с маркет)
Релиз ключ в андроид студио я сделал - ключ загрузки с маркет (Сертификат загрузки с маркета)
в firebase я добавил ключ релиз (Сертификат загрузки с маркета) и ключ (Сертификат подписи приложения с маркета)
В firebase отсутствует дебажний SHA-1
Нужно поставить все три ключа? Дебажний (андроид студио), релиз (Сертификат загрузки с маркет) и маркет (Сертификат подписи приложения с маркет) ???

Comment: Для работы из маркета добавлять дебажный ключ не нужно. Это нужно только для работы в дебажной сборке. Вообще, кажется, вы всё правильно сделали. Пока могу только одну причину придумать - вы ключи добавили, но не обновили в проекте `google-services.json` файл.

Comment: да нет, каждый раз, когда обновляю firebase - скачиваю json файл и вставляю в проект android studio. Все говорят, что проблема где-то в credential (что тоже что то в firebase не внес), но я уже все что знал перепробовал и все что мог найти в интернете, на форумах тоже. Может что то может быть в credential google api? Или это не имеет значения по отношению к этому?

Comment: Может быть и там. У вас авторизация через соц. сети, включая гугл есть в коде?

Comment: да, через фейсбук и гугл.

Comment: А авторизация работает? Если нет - то надо добавить в cloud консоли отпечаток маркетовского ключа

Comment: Если подключить ключ API  (android key в моем случае, ето есть на фото по ссилке) к проекту по отпечатку маркета, тогда при загрузке с маркета приложение работает (авторизация) , но не видно содержымого и если напрямую с андроид студио загрузить приложение на тел., тогда не работает авторизация.

Comment: А если отключить ключ апи, тогда авторизация работает и с маркета и напрямую, но напрямую видно данные, а с маркета нет.    Фото cloud api - https://ibb.co/BCSvwN7 (может я сдесь что-то не так подключаю), а вот как работает firebase при загрузке напрямую на телефон (слева есть данные) и после загрузки с маркета (справа, нет данных) - https://ibb.co/zRmBg8T и в firebase права read and write = true

Comment: Я не очень понимаю что за `android-key` вы имеете в виду. Фотки посмотреть не могу - по ссылкам незнакомым не хожу. Может дело с авторизацией в том, что вы меняете один ключ на другой, а надо не менять, а добавлять?